# Unable to re-use transitions

Tags: d3.js, transition

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/kKvtJ/5/

I have a transition on the click of a `g` which modifies several elements within each `g`. The jsfiddle should make it clear. Click on `10` then `11` then `8` and see how it transitions.

```
nodes_enter.on('click', function(d, i) {
    var all_transition = d3.selectAll('g.bar').transition().duration(500);
    var this_transition = d3.select(this).transition().duration(500);
    all_transition.select('line').attr('opacity',0);
    all_transition.select('text').style('fill','white').attr('x',0);
    this_transition.select('line').attr('opacity',1);
    this_transition.select('text').style('fill','black').attr('x',40);

    // works
    d3.selectAll('g.bar').transition().duration(500)
    // doesn't work
    // all_transition
      .attr('transform', function (e, j) {
          return 'translate(' + (j * 30 + (j > i ? 30 : 0)) + ',0)'
      });
});
```

That works just fine.

However, if I change the last transform's selector to `all_transition`, it does not work correctly when clicking groups left-to-right. Very strange.

If I `console.log` within the transform, it shows the correct coordinates for each group. The browser is not re-rendering the updated transform.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a more accepted way of re-using the `.transition().duration(500)`, or do I have to copy/paste that every time I use it? I thought I could instantiate the transition/duration once on the group, then re-use it over and over with subselectors. Is it expensive to do that for *every* element I want to transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that you're saving the transition, it's that you have multiple interfering transitons. `d3.select(this)` is a subset of `d3.selectAll("g.bar")` and you're attaching transitions to both independently. Thus you get different timers modifying attribute values at the same time and bad things happen.

You don't need the second transition though, you can define everything in terms of the first. You simply need to select all the respective elements and check the data before setting values.

```
var all_transition = d3.selectAll('g.bar').transition().duration(500);
all_transition.selectAll('line').attr('opacity',function(e) { return e == d ? 1 : 0; });
all_transition.selectAll('text').attr('x', function(e) { return e == d ? 40 : 0; });
```

Updated jsfiddle (with what I think you're trying to do) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kKvtJ/6/).

Comment: How do you not already have the mortarboard badge? Thank you so much, have a badge :)